# Is there a C preprocessor that eliminates #ifdefs but also evaluates preprocessor macros?

Tags: c, bash, sed, c-preprocessor

I'm having a project that does lots of this

```
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,37)
// do some legacy stuff
#else
// do current stuff
#endif
```

where `KERNEL_VERSION` is defined as

```
#define KERNEL_VERSION(a,b,c) (((a) << 16) + ((b) << 8) + (c))
```

I'd like to eliminate the defines that are not relevant for the current version, but tools like `sunifdef` don't evaluate the `KERNEL_VERSION` macro, so something like

```
 sunifdef --replace -DKERNEL_VERSION\(a,b,c\)=\(\(\(a\)\<\<16\)+\(\(b\)\<\<8\)+\(c\)\) -DLINUX_VERSION_CODE=3.13.1 *
```

fails with the message

> sunifdef: error 0x04200: Garbage in argument "-DKERNEL_VERSION(a,b,c)=(((a)<<16)+((b)<<8)+(c))"

How do I get around this?

Comment: you probably shouldn't look for a workaround, and trust the developers who wrote the code. probably it *doesn't* work with older kernel versions.

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to do, I want to remove the code for older versions to clean up the file.

Comment: Ugh, this a pre-pre-processor. Oracle took care of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`sunifdef`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sunifdef/) 3.1.3, you can't do it, as you demonstrated. Nor can you do it with earlier versions of `coan` such as 4.2.2.

However, with [`coan`](http://coan2.sourceforge.net/) 5.2 (the current version), you can almost do what you are after.

```
$ cat legacy.c
#define KERNEL_VERSION(a,b,c) (((a) << 16) + ((b) << 8) + (c))
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,37)
do(some,legacy,stuff)
#else
do(current,stuff)
#endif
$ coan source -DLINUX_VERSION_CODE=0x020635 legacy.c
coan: /Users/jleffler/soq/legacy.c: line 1: warning 0x0041c: "-DKERNEL_VERSION(a,b,c)=(((a) << 16) + ((b) << 8) + (c))" has been assumed for the current file
#define KERNEL_VERSION(a,b,c) (((a) << 16) + ((b) << 8) + (c))
do(current,stuff)
$ coan source -DLINUX_VERSION_CODE=0x020624 legacy.c
coan: /Users/jleffler/soq/legacy.c: line 1: warning 0x0041c: "-DKERNEL_VERSION(a,b,c)=(((a) << 16) + ((b) << 8) + (c))" has been assumed for the current file
#define KERNEL_VERSION(a,b,c) (((a) << 16) + ((b) << 8) + (c))
do(some,legacy,stuff)
$
```

This is close to what you want, but not quite.  It gives 'correct' output, but maybe not 'helpful' output.  It gives you the code that would be compiled for the `LINUX_VERSION_CODE` specified on the command line, whereas you'd probably like the conditionals based on `LINUX_VERSION_CODE` and `KERNEL_VERSION` that are not false to survive into the output.

Answer (score 2):

The successor to sunifdef seems to be [coan](http://coan2.sourceforge.net/index.php), and the following command seemed to work (on one simple file):

```
coan source "-DLINUX_VERSION=KERNEL_VERSION(2,18,1)" \
            "-DKERNEL_VERSION(a,b,c)=((a)*0x10000 + (b)*0x100 + (c))" \
            testfile.c
```

I think using the KERNEL_VERSION macro to define LINUX_VERSION is prettier, but you might prefer Chris Dodd's version in hex. Two dots in a number is definitely not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from the fact that you can't define macros with arguments on the command line with `-D` -- you can only define simple macros.  However, you shouldn't NEED to define `KERNEL_VERSION` on the command line as the `#define` in the source should be fine.  You should only need 
 `-DLINUX_VERSION_CODE=0x30d01` -- you need to define it as a single integer constant (hex is easiest) rather than withs dots.

Comment: Complete preprocessors do support defining macros with arguments on the command line. What the OP tried to do would have worked if it was an argument to `gcc` or `clang` instead of `sunifdef`.